# Month view calendar iphone app control for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am on the lookout for calendar control for my iPad app that behaves and looks like the calendar iPhone app when its in month view.

Is anyone aware of any controls that are available?

Comment: Tapku, Open source, it's on github. It has Day and Month, but not List view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Tapku](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) has a nice calendar control

Comment: Agreed, Tapku has a very good calendar. For anyone interested in seeing it in action and info about adding markers to the calendar - I wrote a post about it earlier this year: http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Comment: @Benjamin Pearson: it seems to me (when browsing through the code) that the Tapku calendar isn't localized. Could you confirm if this assumption is correct?

Comment: Does this support day view and week views?

Comment: @Jay spamming your own controls is not the way to go.

Comment: @rckoenes Why down-vote my promotion attempt? All i did was post the control under people who are asking real questions looking for one (just like i was). I did not harass anyone, i simply posted the answer under all i could find. How else would i legally promote it? If you were the one downvoting me could you please at least give my project a chance? If it truly does suck then fine, leave the downvotes. But at least remove the negative rating at least till you try it? I know of no other way to promote my control legally.

Comment: @jay I did not down vote anything. I did flag you comment here as spam. that is all. Also read [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

Comment: @rckoenes ok. my apologies, I thought it was you. Someone went through all my responses and just down voted me twice. If it wasnt you then never mind. Have a good one..

Comment: @Jay please be aware that your self promotion is not obvious and you make it look like you are not the author of the library which you are. Thus most of you answer look like spam and this way of self promoting it frowned upon. You might just want to change the answers to reflect the fact you create this library because X reason. This will make them less spammy, but be aware that this is still not really appreciated on stack overflow as you can read in my links in the previous comment.

Comment: @rckoenes i read them now. I understand. I will add that I created the control and hope for the best. I also mentioned that the control is free (hosted on github) and nonprofit. But yes i understand now. sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

> @Benjamin Pearson: it seems to me (when browsing through the code)
>   that the Tapku calendar isn't localized. Could you confirm if this
>   assumption is correct? – Wolfgang Schreurs Aug 15 at 8:17

Tapku calendar is almost localized as far as iOS user has localized (non-enlish) device. For iOS simulator you need just change the country and Tapku calendar will change Months and Days of the Week in localized language. But for even better localization u will need to change - (NSString*) monthString in ***NSDate+TKCategory.m*** from this:

```
- (NSString*) monthString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}
```

to this:

```
- (NSString*) monthString{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"LLLL"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
}
```

In other words You just need to change MMMM to LLLL. For Russian it will, for example, change "сентября" into "Сентябрь".

Answer (score 2):

You could also try Kal Calendar

[Kal Calendar](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)