# Is there any way to add a calendar view to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, calendar, date, days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Month view calendar iphone app control for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592848/month-view-calendar-iphone-app-control-for-ios)

[Just like this one or something similar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJwjC.jpg) I need to be able to select a date from it by touching a day.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155572/calendar-view-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

- [TapKu](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)
- [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)